# ActiveMQ fails after 40 minutes

Tags: activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ version 5.15 broker (named 31969broker) installed on a Windows Server 2016 (64 bit).  It's been working for a year. There are 8 brokers on 8 peer machines that connect to this server. When one of the peer machines goes down, the ActiveMQ broker fails on this server.  The peers each have a single static, duplex connection to this machine. It (31969broker) has 8 similar connections, one to each peer.  The Transport Connector is openwire.

I performed an experiment where the peer, MUSVRSLDSP1, was offline and there's very little traffic. I restarted the ActiveMQ service. After 39 minutes (and many warnings like below) it threw an exception. The 'wrapper.log' has:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:14 |  WARN | Could not start network bridge between: vm://31969broker and: tcp://MUSVRSLDSP1:61616 due to: MUSVRSLDSP1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |  INFO | Establishing network connection from vm://31969broker to tcp://MUSVRSLDSP1:61616
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 | Exception in thread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[31969broker] Task-6041" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.thread.DedicatedTaskRunner.<init>(DedicatedTaskRunner.java:51)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory.createTaskRunner(TaskRunnerFactory.java:159)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.getTaskRunner(VMTransport.java:328)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.wakeup(VMTransport.java:249)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.start(VMTransport.java:192)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.start(TransportConnection.java:1066)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector$1$1.run(TransportConnector.java:218)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/05/20 15:22:22 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

All I have to do to make the error go away is remove the network connection to the offending peer (MUSVRSLDSP1).  But I can't have the failure of one machine take down the whole messaging system, and that is exactly what happens. If the out of memory error is the culprit, how can I get rid of it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what way do the `OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` messages "appear to be normal"? I would say this is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: A "normal" broker log should never contain OutOfMemoryError

Comment: My broker was connected to about 10 others.  I removed most of them and the problems went away.  I put all of them back but two and things are still good.  One of the suspect ones was having memory and other problems (the other was powered down) so I think I have my answer.  But a failure to a peer should not cause my broker to crash.

Comment: I have edited the question and added details.  I'm still in desperate need of help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to set the following to false in the wrapper.conf file:

> wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=false

I hope this can help someone else.